# How do I make an Arraylist have the same size?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

how do I make two arraylist with the same size

like when I stop at index 5 in the first arraylist the second array list will automatically stop when i reach the index 5

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        ArrayList <String> title = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList <String> description = new ArrayList<>();

        int i = 0;
        int d = 0;


        String n = in.nextLine();
        while(!n.equals(" ")){
         System.out.println("Enter a movie title");
            title.add(n);
            n = in.nextLine();
}


        for(;i < title.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("[" + i+"]" +title.get(i));
} 

        description = new ArrayList<>(title.size());
        String m = in.nextLine();
        while(!m.equals(" ")){
            System.out.println("Enter the movie Description");
            description.add(m);
            m = in.nextLine();
}
        description.remove(0);
        for(;d < description.size(); d++){
                   System.out.println("Description for ["+d+"]"+title.get(d)+":"+description.get(d) );


}
}
}
```

Comment: From the problem i see, you are using two Array list for title and description, wont it be better to use a HashMap<String,String> instead of an ArrayList, where you hold both the data?

Comment: Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it!!! Create a class with 2 fields, and make a list of that. Don't create conjoined lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a break statement.

```
// I'm assuming here is where you want it.

// description = new ArrayList<>(title.size());
String m = in.nextLine();
while(!m.equals(" ") && description.size() < title.size()){
    System.out.println("Enter the movie Description");
    description.add(m);
    m = in.nextLine();
}
```

If you really want the same amount, then don't allow them to exit.

```
String m = in.nextLine();
while(description.size() < title.size()){
    System.out.println("Enter the movie Description");
    description.add(m);
    m = in.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
for(;d < description.size() && d < title.size(); d++)
```

This still does not ensure that there are equally many titles and descriptions.

Perhaps you also want to move `int i = 0;` and `int d = 0;` into the head of their corresponding for-loops (like `for(int i = 0; i < title.size(); i++)`). And you may want to change your while-loops to do-while-loops to avoid inserting (and even waiting/"asking" for) the first input line, which will be read before your prompt is written.